# What Event or method is needed to set user defined field immediately after assigned a InvoiceNbr/RefNbr

Tags: acumatica

I have been scratching my head on this one for too long now so I am reaching out in hope of getting some help with it.

The primary objective is the following:

When we save a record, we need to call out to a web service to get a value and store that value into a User Defined Field. The invoice number that is assigned to the invoice is required by the Web Method call so this needs to be populated prior to the web method call and preferably before the final Persist Call.

My initial approach was to use a Field Level event on the RefNbr field but I’m not getting the desired end result as most of them return the “NEW” value as the RefNbr and can’t seem to find an event that will fire when this field is assigned the final invoice number but before the final save. This is what I have observed with the following events

ARInvoice_RefNbr_FieldUpdated – this does not appear to fire when the RefNbr is set.

ARInvoice_RowInserting – this fires before the save button is hit and holds the NEW value

ARInvoice_RowUpdating – When this fires it is also holding the NEW value.

ARInvoice_RowPersisting – this fires immediately after the save button are hit but the row still contains the NEW value.

ARInvoice_RowPersisted – This fires with the correct Invoice number. But the record appears to already be saved. We get a Key but on refresh, it disappears.

The second approach I took was to set the UDF post-Persist () then resave the record once the UDF is populated.

The code I submitted depicts what I have tried so far with my observations commented.

Thank You for the help
Robert

```
public class CtpARInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{
//... unrelated code removed
public delegate void PersistDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        //Getting the ClickToPay Key does not work if we are attempting to get it before or
        //after the baseMethod call.

        //IF we try to get it before we will be sending in <NEW> as 
        //the invoice number.

        //If we send it after the base Method Call we get the correct Key and it seems things are copacetic.
        //But if we hit the refresh button the end result is the key disapears 

        //My initial thoughts where to look into implementing this at the FieldUpdating event as well as several other event handlers
        //including FieldUpdated, RowInserting, RowUpdating, RowPersisting, FieldVerifying...
        //none of these are leading to a case where we can get the CtpKey between the time we get a valid 
        //Invoice Nbr and the final persisting of the record.
        //We only get a RefNbr of <NEW> in each of the above cases.

        //GetClickToPayKey() Calling this before sends <NEW> as the invoice number
        baseMethod();
        GetClickToPayKey(baseMethod);

    }

    private void GetClickToPayKey(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        GetClickToPayKey();
        if (SaveAfterCtpKeyIsSet)
        {
            SaveAfterCtpKeyIsSet = false;// prevent any duplicate Calls
            Persist(baseMethod);
        }
    }

    private void GetClickToPayKey()
    {

        ARInvoice invoice = Base.CurrentDocument.Select();
        if (invoice.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) return;
        CtpARInvoiceExt invoiceExt = PXCache<ARInvoice>.GetExtension<CtpARInvoiceExt>(invoice);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceExt.UsrCtpKey)) return;

        var ctpAcumatica = CtpAcumatica.Create(Base);
        try
        {
            invoiceExt.UsrCtpKey = ctpAcumatica.GetCtpKey(invoice);
            invoiceExt.UsrCtpUrl = BuildCtpUrl(invoiceExt.UsrCtpKey);
            //Neither the PressSave() nor Update() existed when the first approch was attempted.
            Base.CurrentDocument.Cache.Update(invoiceExt);
            Base.Actions.PressSave(); //does not get the desired results either.
            //the second save will not occur unless this is set to true.
            //If we do not invoke the second save the key will be present 
            //only until the refresh button is clicked where it then disappears. 
            SaveAfterCtpKeyIsSet = true;

        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored Allow saving even if the C2P server cannot be reached.  TODO: Verify that is okay
        }

    }

    private bool SaveAfterCtpKeyIsSet { get; set; }

    private string BuildCtpUrl(string ctpKey)
    {
        return CtpSetupData.Current.CtpPortalUrl + '/' + ctpKey;
    }

    //protected void ARInvoice_RefNbr_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    //When we save the RefNbr get the actual invoice number but 
    //    //This Event Handler does not appear to be called.
    //    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    //    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
    //    //does not yield desired end result
    //}

    //protected void ARInvoice_RowInserting(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    //    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
    //    //does not yield desired end result
    //}

    //protected void ARInvoice_RowUpdating(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    //    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
    //    //does not yield desired end result
    //}

    //protected void ARInvoice_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    //    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
    //    //does not yield desired end result
    //}



    //protected void ARInvoice_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    //    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
    //    //does not yield desired end result
    //}



    ////protected void ARInvoice_RefNbr_FieldUpdating(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    ////{

    ////    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    ////    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();

    ////}



    //protected void ARInvoice_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    //    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
    //    //does not yield desired end result
    //}



    //protected void ARInvoice_RefNbr_FieldVerifying(PXCache cache, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    //    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
    //    //does not yield desired end result
    //}



    ////protected void ARInvoice_RefNbr_FieldUpdating(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
    ////{

    ////    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    ////    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();

    ////}



    //protected void ARInvoice_RefNbr_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
    //    if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
    //    //does not yield desired end result
    //}


}
```

Notes regarding the First approach

```
private void GetClickToPayKey()
    {

        ARInvoice invoice = Base.CurrentDocument.Select();
        if (invoice.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) return;
        CtpARInvoiceExt invoiceExt = PXCache<ARInvoice>.GetExtension<CtpARInvoiceExt>(invoice);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceExt.UsrCtpKey)) return;

        var ctpAcumatica = CtpAcumatica.Create(Base);
        try
        {
            invoiceExt.UsrCtpKey = ctpAcumatica.GetCtpKey(invoice);
            invoiceExt.UsrCtpUrl = BuildCtpUrl(invoiceExt.UsrCtpKey);

            /* this code below was only attempted with the second approach
             and was not used when attempting the first and ideal approach using 
             field row level event handlers.
            Base.CurrentDocument.Cache.Update(invoiceExt);
            Base.Actions.PressSave(); //does not get the desired results either.
            //the second save will not occur unless this is set to true.
            //If we do not invoke the second save the key will be present 
            //only until the refresh button is clicked where it then disappears. 
            SaveAfterCtpKeyIsSet = true;
            */
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored Allow saving even if the C2P server cannot be reached.  TODO: Verify that is okay
        }

    }

    protected void ARInvoice_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {

        var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
        if (row.RefNbr != null && !row.RefNbr.Contains("<NEW>")) GetClickToPayKey();
        //does not yield desired end result
        //the issue with using this event or similar ones is the row.RefNbr is returning <NEW>
        //We need to call the web service only when the Actual invoice is assigned.
    }
```

Comment: If you need to change a value just before it's persisted you should use RowPersisting. I doubt your error is selecting the right event. It seems more likely that you're making a technical error in GetClickToPayKey method. At a glance I see many wrong things in there. You shouldn't call save action (PressSave) from a RowPersisting event, that will just lead to infinite loop logic. There should not be a second save, that's just terrible. You shouldn't use the extended cache as parameter for update, should be Cache.Update(invoice). etc...

Comment: Besides technical error there could be logical error too, debug to make sure your conditions doesn't call return to bail out prematurely of GetClickToPayKey method before you assign the field values. I would test with more simple assignation (no api calls, no condition) or would make 100% sure the code path expected is being hit.

Comment: I should have added notes to the GetClickToPayKey method to indicate the current context it was running is the second approach mentioned trying to resave after the first persist. When I had the events wired attempting first approach the lines for Action.PressSave nor the ...Cache.Update(var) did not exist. I agree the second save is not the ideal approach. thanks for the feedback I will look into this and keep trying with RowPersisting.

Comment: HB_ACUMATICA, I have added additional notes to clarify how the first approach was attempted. I have retried using the RowPersisting event. The reason this is not working is the row still holds the <NEW> value when I need to call the method when it is finally assigned an actual invoice.

Comment: I also found my original post had the greater-than less-than values which were removed by Stack overflow preventing that point to get across. I have modified to remove those chars.

Comment: You have a Persist after Persist issue, this pattern is always problematic in my experience. You will get ID only after it's persisted to database but if you call Persist from Persist you're in for much bigger trouble. There's two way out of it that I know of, Persist using another graph so it doesn't cycle in an endless loop or use a Persist operation that isn't a graph like Cache.Persist or even a PXDatabase operation in worst cases. As for where to do that, in Persist() override or maybe RowPersisted.

Comment: There are many examples of it in the framework source code, if you search for "override void Persist()" you'll find examples like in APDocumentRelease.Persist

Comment: I will continue to look through the source for any clues that might point me in the right direction. So far everything I have tried is not returning results. I tried to explicitly set the RefNbr prior to the persist call but that errors out. I'm not able to do that manually through the UI so I assume we cant set this prior to the persist method call. Seems the persist needs to fire before we can get the RefNbr out. I have tried to wire into the RowPersisted Event and can set the value but I'm unable to save from that point. The UI save button is not even available.

Comment: You must never call the Save action during the Save action operation, that's the Persist in Persist anti-pattern. No matter which event you use or which way you use to call the Save action you will end up in a logical dead-end infinite loop. So the issue is not that you're unable to call the Save action, the issue is that you're trying to call the Save action. That's why I pointed towards APDocumentRelease.Persist override which persist the changes using Cache.Persist instead of the Save action. Try saving using other mechanism than Save action like is done in Persist() override.

Comment: And yes auto-generated key fields will be null until Persisted on database.

Comment: I totally get the Persist in Persist concern and certainly want to avoid it. It seems however we are dependent on executing a full persist before we can get the assigned RefNbr so the primary question is how can we safely persist Udf that is generated from a method that needs the RefNbr? I have being trying to implement the Cache.Persist based off of the code in APDocumentRelease.Persist. I suspect that this being a DAC extension makes this case different. I tried cache.SetValueExt<CtpARInvoiceExt.usrCtpKey>(row,"Test1234"); but this does the same... We see the key, refresh, it's gone.

Comment: There's not much point in using SetValueExt in Persist override method as there are no more events that should go on when Persisting. Basically when the Save button is hit, you should stop generating events, just save and exit asap. RefNbr should be avail in Persist() override without any other trickery. In rare cases it's possible that Cache.Persist fails so worst case scenario can be resolved with PXDatabase.Update which saves to database without launching other events or spurious validation.

Comment: I had tried the SetValueExt in the persisted event. the RefNbr only becomes available when the PersistDelegate baseMethod method gets called. if you try to get it before you get <NEW>

Comment: That's the behavior by design. IDs are generated during persist so you can only get them from "public override void Persist()" and "RowPersisted" events. From there you should be able to modify the ARInvoice record and persist it using:  Base.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Update); In some rare cases where Cache.Persist fails because of validation events using PXDatabase.Update<ARInvoice>(…) can be used to persist the changes.

Comment: Negative, after implementing Base.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Update) I get the same behavior. See the key populated, refresh, Gone. I just want to confirm that Base.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)] is what I am looking for when its a DAC Extention that is getting populated?

Comment: Check in database table to confirm it is not saving. The pattern should be invoiceExt.CustomField = your_value and then Base.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Update). Like I said it's possible (although very rare) that you can't save with Cach.Persist. When that's the case you need to use PXDatabase.Update to save more directly to DB. There's no need to look at anything in UI, the purpose of Persist() override is to do non UI operation.

Comment: I'm going to look into using PXDatabase.Update. I got the end result we need by recalling for the key in RowSelected if the value is empty and the RefNbr is populated. I very certain however this is going to be frowned upon. Most of this stuff comes into play once the invoice is released and the Key saves fine on release. We have an edge case where an invoice can be printed prior to release and this field needs to be present thus the reason we are looking to get it on save. I'll keep you posted on how I make out.

Comment: Yay!!! using a PXDatabase.Update worked. I appreciate you pointing that option out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was certainly a head-scratcher. 
So this particular requirement was a catch-22. We needed to initialize the record with some UDF values within the scope of a users saving the record. The logic of determining the content of these UDFs was dependent on having an Assigned RefNbr or InvoiceNbr but we were unable to get it prior to the Persist method completing. I tried several alternatives of invoking another persist equivalent after the original but they seemed to not have any effect on persisting the back end data as when we refreshed the values where gone. So I assume Acumatica has blocked the ability to persist after the first persist occurs as this is likely deemed a persist in persist anti-pattern. To overcome this I used a PXDatabase Update and this got us to the end result we are looking for. Special thanks to HB_Acumatica for the guidance during this troubleshooting process. Here is the code that got to the end result.

```
   //Within the Overridden Persist method of the Graph Extention.
   baseMethod(); //Can not get RefNbr until this is finished.
   //... logic to populate UDFValues    
   PXDatabase.Update<ARInvoice>(
            new PXDataFieldAssign<CtpARInvoiceExt.usrCtpKey>(invoiceExt.UsrYourKey),
            new PXDataFieldAssign<CtpARInvoiceExt.usrCtpUrl>(invoiceExt.UsrYourUrl),
            new PXDataFieldRestrict<ARInvoice.refNbr>(Base.CurrentDocument.Current.RefNbr));
```